# How to make a clickable transition bar graph in d3 v4?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How to make a clickable transition bar graph in d3 v4?

Current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3: A bar chart that transitions to new data!</title>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            /* No style rules here yet */       
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <p>Click on this text to update the chart with new data values (once).</p>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            //Width and height
            var w = 600;
            var h = 250;

            var dataset = [ 5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13,
                            11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25 ];

            var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
                            .rangeRound([0, w])
                            .padding(0.05);

            var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                            .domain([0, d3.max(dataset)])
                            .range([0, h]);

            //Create SVG element
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h);
            //Create bars
            svg.selectAll("rect")
               .data(dataset)
               .enter()
               .append("rect")
               .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    return xScale(i);
               })
               .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return h - yScale(d);
               })
               .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
               .attr("height", function(d) {
                    return yScale(d);
               })
               .attr("fill", function(d) {
                    return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d * 10) + ")";
               });
            //Create labels
            svg.selectAll("text")
               .data(dataset)
               .enter()
               .append("text")
               .text(function(d) {
                    return d;
               })
               .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
               .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    return xScale(i) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2;
               })
               .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return h - yScale(d) + 14;
               })
               .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
               .attr("font-size", "11px")
               .attr("fill", "white");
            //On click, update with new data            
            d3.select("p")
                .on("click", function() {
                    //New values for dataset
                    dataset = [ 11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25,
                                5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13 ];
                    //Update all rects
                    svg.selectAll("rect")
                       .data(dataset)
                       .transition()                                // <-- This makes it a smooth transition!
                       .attr("y", function(d) {
                            return h - yScale(d);
                       })
                       .attr("height", function(d) {
                            return yScale(d);
                       })
                       .attr("fill", function(d) {
                            return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d * 10) + ")";
                       });
                    //Update all labels
                    svg.selectAll("text")
                       .data(dataset)
                       .text(function(d) {
                            return d;
                       })
                       .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                            return xScale(i) + xScale.band() / 2;
                       })
                       .attr("y", function(d) {
                            return h - yScale(d) + 14;
                       });

                });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Code above from: 
https://github.com/alignedleft/d3-book/blob/master/chapter_09/05_transition.html
http://examples.oreilly.com/0636920026938/chapter_09/05_transition.html

I am getting errors after switching the code to v4. I fixed the errors I knew about but now I am getting these one errors in the JavaScript console:

Error:  attribute x: Expected length, "NaN".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting the domain of the x scale:

```
var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(d3.range(dataset.lengh))
    .rangeRound([0, w])
    .padding(0.1);
```

Also, pay attention to `xScale.band()`, which doesn't exist: it should be `xScale.bandwidth()` instead.

Here is a working code, with the domain:

```js
var w = 600;
 var h = 250;

 var dataset = [5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13,
   11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25
 ];

 var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
   .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
   .rangeRound([0, w])
   .padding(0.1);

 var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
   .domain([0, d3.max(dataset)])
   .range([0, h]);

 //Create SVG element
 var svg = d3.select("body")
   .append("svg")
   .attr("width", w)
   .attr("height", h);
 //Create bars
 svg.selectAll("rect")
   .data(dataset)
   .enter()
   .append("rect")
   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
     return xScale(i);
   })
   .attr("y", function(d) {
     return h - yScale(d);
   })
   .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
   .attr("height", function(d) {
     return yScale(d);
   })
   .attr("fill", function(d) {
     return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d * 10) + ")";
   });
 //Create labels
 svg.selectAll("text")
   .data(dataset)
   .enter()
   .append("text")
   .text(function(d) {
     return d;
   })
   .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
     return xScale(i) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2;
   })
   .attr("y", function(d) {
     return h - yScale(d) + 14;
   })
   .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
   .attr("font-size", "11px")
   .attr("fill", "white");
 //On click, update with new data            
 d3.select("p")
   .on("click", function() {
     //New values for dataset
     dataset = [11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25,
       5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13
     ];
     //Update all rects
     svg.selectAll("rect")
       .data(dataset)
       .transition() // <-- This makes it a smooth transition!
       .attr("y", function(d) {
         return h - yScale(d);
       })
       .attr("height", function(d) {
         return yScale(d);
       })
       .attr("fill", function(d) {
         return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d * 10) + ")";
       });
     //Update all labels
     svg.selectAll("text")
       .data(dataset)
       .text(function(d) {
         return d;
       })
       .attr("y", function(d) {
         return h - yScale(d) + 14;
       });

   });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<p>Click on this text to update the chart with new data values (once).</p>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it so that there are 3 different graphs involved? So that it automatically loads graph 1, and then when you click it shows graph 2, and then when you click again it shows graph 3, and finally if you click again it goes back to graph 1?

Comment: Yes, there is, but you should post *another* question regarding this. Let's keep it 1 problem per question. Besides that, if you ask this here, in the comments, I'm probably the only one reading it... on the other hand, if you post a new question, everybody is gonna read it.